# business layer 3

Tags: architecture, layer

Why the second layer in 3 layer model known as "Business" layer?

Comment: So tell us what should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its specific to the nature of the application - a charity, online retailler and estate agents might all use the same webserver and database - but the bit in the middle is very different.

Comment: I don't think they'd use the same database, they are different topics.  Maybe you meant same db server.

Answer (score 2):

Because the *business logic* resides there. That is - the logic that is specific to the business scenarios.

Other layers should not have such logic. Front end should display and gather data, database should store data, dao should retrieve and save data.

The business layer should perform the logic based on what is coming as input from the UI, and from the DB.

It's 'business', because every software backs some business.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here my 2 cents.

Why? Because that is how it is *defined* in the **N-Tier paradigm**. We cannot ask why something is named as such when it is defined as such.

N-Tier paradigm is an old one - more than 10 years old. N-Tiere design while at some point helped separating view logic from business logic, now is not trendy anymore.

Today, [Domain Driven Design](http://domaindrivendesign.org/resources/what_is_ddd) aka DDD is the new paradigm where looks at the domain logic and builds the system on that. **Domain logic is everywhere, in database, in the UI as well as in the middle layer**. So really your tables will be called `Order`, `Topping`, etc if you are making software for pizza shops whil it will have `Account`, `Transaction` if you are developing software for a bank. **So business logic is everywhere,** in the middle tier as well as in the UI or database.

So now while **layered architecture** is still accepted as a good architectural approach (which has a middle layer which is **not** called "business layer" anymore), N-Tier is not.

Comment: I don't quite agree. First, DDD is not new at all. Then, with DDD the domain logic is only in the domain objects. Not on the UI, not in the database. And the domain objects represent the 'business layer'

Comment: Domain objects are entities. They do not represent business layer. They in fact reside in the data layer.

Comment: yes, they are entities. But they are not the DAO layer - there is a separate layer taking care of database operations (repositories). And the thin service layer is responsible for coordinating domain objects. So still, the business logic is not scattered as you say.

Comment: They are not just at data layer, they are everywhere, from data up to UI. But since you need to create a dependency hierarchy, they are at the top of the depdendency where every libraray has reference to.

Answer (score 0):

In an OO application I like to think of the business layer as business rules, processes or workflows that are applied to the objects. However in many cases I have seen this to mean that the objects become nothing but POCO's (Plain Old C# Objects in C#, POJO's in Java etc). The problem with this is that the object's behaviour becomes detached from the object and moved into arbitrary "Business Logic" classes.

My personal belief is that the "Business Layer" should act upon objects but not replace object an object's behaviour.  This also allows for better implementation of other practices such as Open Closed Principle using inheritance and polymorphism.

Consider this example ["OCP"](http://joelabrahamsson.com/a-simple-example-of-the-openclosed-principle/) where the Area class would be the "Business Layer" but the various Shape objects contain the behaviour logic for each type of shape. This way the Area code rarely, if at all needs to change.